# Convert php array with indexed format

Tags: php

This is my array

```
Array
(
    [JANETS] => 2
    [ROYR] => 2
)
```

I want to convert this format.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => JANETS
            [count] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
           [name] => ROYR
           [count] => 2
        )
)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not magento related

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = ...your array here;
$processed = array_map(
    function ($item, $key) {
        return ['name' => $key, 'count' => $item];
    },
    $arr,
    array_keys($arr)
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$mainArray=[];

$mainArray[]=[
    'name' => 'JANETS',
    'count' => 2
];

$mainArray[]=[
    'name' => 'ROYR',
    'count' => 2
];
echo "<pre>";
print_r($mainArray);
exit;
```